# jQuery Dropdown .slideUp/Down works on Chrome, Bugs on Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

First of all, I'm starting to learn javascript now, so I know my code is crap

But it worked for me on Chrome! Only when I tried to view it on Firefox, it was bugged

## Fiddle: [jsfiddle.net/7NCcY/](http://jsfiddle.net/7NCcY/)

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
                $(document).ready(function(){
                    /* Dropdown Webmail */
                    $('.button-webmail').click(function() {
                        if($('.toggle-webmail').is(':visible')) {
                            $('.toggle-webmail').slideUp(200);
                        }
                        else {
                            $('.toggle-webmail').slideDown(200);
                            $('.toggle-client-area').slideUp(200);
                            $('.toggle-all-products').slideUp(200);
                            $('.toggle-countries').slideUp(200);
                        }
                    });
                    /* Dropdown Client Area */
                    $('.button-client-area').click(function() {
                        if($('.toggle-client-area').is(':visible')) {
                            $('.toggle-client-area').slideUp(200);
                        }
                        else {
                            $('.toggle-client-area').slideDown(200);
                            $('.toggle-webmail').slideUp(200);
                            $('.toggle-all-products').slideUp(200);
                            $('.toggle-products').slideUp(200);
                        }
                    });
                    /* Dropdown All Products */
                    $('.button-all-products').click(function() {
                        if($('.toggle-all-products').is(':visible')) {
                            $('.toggle-all-products').slideUp(200);
                        }
                        else {
                            $('.toggle-all-products').slideDown(200);
                            $('.toggle-webmail').slideUp(200);
                            $('.toggle-client-area').slideUp(200);
                            $('.toggle-countries').slideUp(200);
                        }
                    });
                    /* Dropdown Countries */
                    $('.button-countries').click(function() {
                        if($('.toggle-countries').is(':visible')) {
                            $('.toggle-countries').slideUp(200);
                        }
                        else {
                            $('.toggle-countries').slideDown(200);
                            $('.toggle-webmail').slideUp(200);
                            $('.toggle-client-area').slideUp(200);
                            $('.toggle-all-products').slideUp(200);
                        }
                    });
                    $('html').click(function() {
                        $('.toggle-webmail, .toggle-client-area, .toggle-all-products, .toggle-countries').slideUp(200);
                    });
                    $('.toggle-webmail, .toggle-client-area, .toggle-all-products, .toggle-countries').click(function(event){
                        event.stopPropagation();
                    });
                });
</script>
<style>
.container {
width:100%;
}
.column1, .column2, .column3, .column4 {
    width:20%;
    margin-right:5%;
    float:left;
}
.toggle-webmail, .toggle-client-area, .toggle-all-products, .toggle-countries {
    display:none;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Click to dropdown</h1>
<h2>Works on Chrome. Bugs on Firefox</h2>
<div class="container">
    <div class="column1">
        <div class="button-webmail">Webmail</div>
        <div class="toggle-webmail"><input type="text"></input></div>
    </div>
    <div class="column2">
        <div class="button-client-area">Client Area</div>
        <div class="toggle-client-area"><input type="text"></input></div>
    </div>
    <div class="column3">
        <div class="button-all-products">All Products</div>
        <div class="toggle-all-products"><input type="text"></input></div>
    </div>
    <div class="column4">
        <div class="button-countries">Countries</div>
        <div class="toggle-countries"><input type="text"></input></div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: As a start, you can drastically reduce your code by thinking a bit more modularly. For instance, your columns can all have the class of `.column` and then you can style the things they have in common, and use a more specific `.column1` for styles specific to that column. In that same way, you can assume that all of your "toggle" buttons share certain things as well and reduce the redundancy.

Comment: Also, firefox is very strict, so it's not a firefox bug, it's just not excellent code, like you said.

Comment: you can also separate classes with commas instead of repeating.

`$('.toggle-countries, .other-thing, .other-other-thing').slideDown(200);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Always check your console!

The main issue is the way Chrome and Firefox handles `event.stopPropagation()`.  As a tip, when you are debugging JQuery, one of the first things you should always do is to check the console.  In your JSFiddle, when you click on a button on Firefox, you'll find that the console outputs

`ReferenceError: event is not defined`

`event.stopPropogation()` stops your click from triggering the onclick handler for `$('html')`.  Since Firefox could not call that method, your click bubbled up to the onclick handler for `$('html')`, which ultimately closed the dropdown as soon as slid down.

To fix this, you need to add in the `event` parameter to your click handler.  For example:

```
$('.button-webmail').click(function(event) {

    /* handle click */

    event.stopPropagation();
}
```

[JSFiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/asb4J/1/)

It just so happened that Chrome work correctly without this event parameter.  Hope this clears things up!

Also, as @sheriffderek pointed out, there are many ways that this code could be cleaned up.  You should definitely look into his ideas!

Comment: That's precisely the problem, I'll keep an eye on the console, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This isn't exactly what you want... but it'll get you cleaned up and send you on your way, I hope:  [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/8QjGD/)   - hope this helps. Properly targeting with CSS really helps a lot.

### HTML

```
<div class="column webmail">
    <div class="menu-button">Webmail</div>
    <div class="toggle-field"><input type="text"></input></div>
</div>

<div class="column client-area">
    <div class="menu-button">Client Area</div>
    <div class="toggle-field"><input type="text"></input></div>
</div>

<div class="column all-products">
    <div class="menu-button">All Products</div>
    <div class="toggle-field"><input type="text"></input></div>
</div>

<div class="column countries">
    <div class="menu-button">Countries</div>
    <div class="toggle-field"><input type="text"></input></div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.column {
    width:20%;
    margin-right:5%;
    float:left;
}

.menu-button {
    border: 1px solid red;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.toggle-field {
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

### jQuery

```
// hide all fields

$('.toggle-field').hide();



// webmail "when you click a menu button, find the next .toggle-field and toggle it

$('.menu-button').on("click", function() {

    $(".toggle-field").hide(),
    $(this).next(".toggle-field").slideToggle(100);

});
```

Comment: (this) refers to the thing the event is happening to... so .menu-button